# How to make a certain function stop executing when a certain condition is met

Tags: python, discord.py

I am designing a discord bot that loops certain text when a certain conditions are met, which then triggers this function to run.

```
async def inform(self,message):
    while flag==1:
        await message.channel.send("text")
        await asyncio.sleep(5) 
        await message.channel.send("text2")
        await asyncio.sleep(5) 
        await message.channel.send("text3")
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
```

Now the problem is when the conditions are not met anymore the function completes the entire cycle before haulting. I want it to stop the moment the condition is not satisfied anymore.

I thought of adding an

```
if flag==0:
 return
```

After every line but that is not the elegant solution I am looking for.

I don't want the entire code to stop running, but just this function.

I am a beginner to python and any insights are welcome :)
Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `while loop`, before each iteration will look if the condition is **True**, if it is, it will continue, if not it will stop.

```py
while flag == 1:
    if 'some condition met':
        flag = 0
        # And the loop will stop
```

The loop will stop by itself, nothing more. Also it's better to use booleans.

Here's your code a bit improved

```
# Defining variables
flag = True
iteration = 0

while flag:
    # Adding `1` each iteration
    iteration += 1
    # Sending the message
    await message.channel.send(f'text{iteration}')
    # Sleeping
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
```

Comment: But what if the sleep duration for each message is different?
How do I incorporate that ?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: I mean that you are iterating through text messages in a file right? But now you're assuming a constant time gap of 5s between those messages. What if I want a different sleep period between each message?

Comment: That's basic math, you can do something with the variable `iteration`. i.e: `sleep_time = i * 5` (the first iteration it will sleep 5 seconds, the second iteration 10 seconds...)

Comment: But I dont want a sequence like that.
I want a predefined sleep time for each message.
Example:
Message 1- sleep 5s
Message 2 -sleep 3s Message-3 sleep 6s

Comment: You'll need to find a pattern there and do it mathematically then. Or you can use `random.randint` if you don't  care what values you get

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right, You want to check if a condition is met. Here is an infinite loop until some criteria is met. If this is not what you wanted please explain it again.

```py
import random
msgs = ['msg1','msg2','msg3']
condition_met = False
while True:
    if condition_met:
        break
        # also return works here
    else:
        await message.channel.send(random.choise(msgs))
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        if something == 'Condition met here':
            condition_met = True
```

Comment: Sorry but this is not what I mean.
Suppose someone sends a message in discord and that triggers the bot to run a predefined list of messages one after the other in a loop until they trigger the stop response again.
But in my code when the stop response is triggered it doesnt stop executing instantaneously but stops after one function cycle is completed once, but
I want the function to stop running the moment the stop trigger is sent.

In your code you have only included 1 text message, but i want different text messages to be sent one after the other

Answer (score -2):

Each iteration of the loop should only send one message, to keep track of the order of messages sent, I used the variable `i` which is incremented every time a message is sent.

```py
async def inform(self,message):
    i = 0
    while flag==1:
        if i == 0:
            await message.channel.send("text")
            await asyncio.sleep(5) 
        elif i == 1:
            await message.channel.send("text2")
            await asyncio.sleep(5)
        elif i == 2:
            await message.channel.send("text3")
            await asyncio.sleep(5)
        i = (i + 1) % 3
```

Comment: This is not the best method to do it in Python

Comment: @Abdulaziz Then what is?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @RoyCohen but what if there are alot of such texts, wouldnt that be cumbersome and not so efficient?

Comment: @BananaBamboo If you have those text in a list you can use `i` as an index. I think that even with a lot of texts the code will remain relatively efficient but it would get cumbersome.